# React-Router open Link in new tab

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Is there a way to get [React Router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router) to open a link in new tab? I tried this and it did not work.

```
<Link to="chart" target="_blank" query={{test: this.props.test}} >Test</Link>
```

It's possible to fluff it by adding something like `onClick="foo"` to the Link like what I have above, but there would be a console error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I think Link component does not have the props for it.

You can have alternative way by create a  tag and use the makeHref method of Navigation mixin to create your url

```
<a target='_blank' href={this.makeHref(routeConsts.CHECK_DOMAIN, {},
   { realm: userStore.getState().realms[0].name })}>
        Share this link to your webmaster
</a>
```

Comment: here it is calling href self calling function,
it will cause re-render 
ALERT!

Comment: I believe the makeHref function was renamed to createHref and since removed. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35066996/6004931 https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/issues/365

Answer (score 267):

Since React Router version 5.0.1, you can use:

```
<Link to="route" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" />
```

Comment: @AbhishekNalin How to get this.makeHref and send parameter in side this.makeHref

Comment: In react-router 5.0.1, it seems adding `target="_blank"` is enough to do the trick.

Comment: Note [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30202755/react-router-open-link-in-new-tab#comment97244148_41582565) comment. Use `rel='noopener noreferrer'` if you use `target="_blank"`

Comment: Thank you! `target="_blank"` worked for me :) in react-router 5.0.1

Comment: funny, this does not work in the previous version ;)

Comment: "Latest" version as of 11/18/2020 is 5.2.0. You can check on the npm page. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router under the "Versions" tab.

Answer (score 40):

> We can use the following options:-

```
 // first option is:-
    <Link to="myRoute" params={myParams} target="_blank">

 // second option is:-
    var href = this.props.history.createHref('myRoute', myParams);
    <a href={href} target="_blank">

 //third option is:-
    var href = '/myRoute/' + myParams.foo + '/' + myParams.bar;
    <a href={href} target="_blank">
```

> We can use either of three option to open in new tab by react routing.

Comment: some iPhones ignore "target='_blank'". It seems like this would still fail for those phones.

Comment: Note about `target='_blank'`: recommend adding [`rel='noopener noreferrer'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50709625/link-with-target-blank-and-rel-noopener-noreferrer-still-vulnerable) to your `<a>` tag

Comment: If linking to another page on your own site, `rel='noopener noreferrer'` should not be a concern, correct?

Answer (score 26):

You can use "{}" for the target, then jsx will not cry

```
<Link target={"_blank"} to="your-link">Your Link</Link>
```

Answer (score 25):

For external link simply use  an achor in place of Link:

```
<a rel="noopener noreferrer" href="http://url.com" target="_blank">Link Here</a>
```

Comment: The reason for the `rel="noopener noreferrer"` can be found here https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener/

Answer (score 14):

Starting with react_router 1.0, the props will be passed onto the anchor tag. You can directly use `target="_blank"`. Discussed here: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/2188

Answer (score 13):

```
<Link to={{  pathname: "https://github.com/vinothsmart/" }} target="_blank" />
```

This code fine works like a href="" target="_blank"

Answer (score 11):

In my case, I am using another function.

Function

```
 function openTab() {
    window.open('https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.drishya');
  }

  <Link onClick={openTab}></Link>
```

Answer (score 7):

This works without the need to import react-router or external libraries.
Moreover, Chrome is not considering a popoup so window is not blocked.

```
<button onClick={() => window.open("https://google.com.ar")} />
```

Or if you want to use a string variable

```
<button onClick={() => window.open(redirectUrl.toString())} />
```

Comment: `<button onClick={() => window.open("https://google.com.ar", "_blank")} />`


You can also add features: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#progressive_enhancement :


`<button onClick={() => window.open("https://google.com.ar", "_blank", "noopener,noreferrer")} />`

Comment: this is inaccessible code.  Please use proper semantics.  For links an `a` tag should be used, not a button.

https://www.digitala11y.com/links-vs-buttons-a-perennial-problem/

Answer (score 4):

The simples way is to use 'to' property:

```
<Link to="chart" target="_blank" to="http://link2external.page.com" >Test</Link>
```

Answer (score 4):

this works fine for me

```
<Link to={`link`} target="_blank">View</Link>
```

Answer (score 4):

To open an url in a new tab, you can use the Link tag as below:

```
<Link to="/yourRoute" target="_blank">
    Open YourRoute in a new tab
</Link>
```

It's nice to keep in mind that the `<Link>` element gets translated to an `<a>` element, and as per [react-router-dom docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link/others), you can pass any props you'd like to be on it such as title, id, className, etc.

Answer (score 1):

`target="_blank"` is enough to open in a new tab, when you are using react-router

eg:

```
<Link to={`/admin/posts/error-post-list/${this.props.errorDate}`} target="_blank"> View Details </Link>`
```

Answer (score 1):

for me this was the best

```
onClick={() => window.open("https://facebook.com")}
```

if you want to open in another tab

```
onClick={() => window.open("https://facebook.com", "_blank")}
```

Comment: This solution has nothing to do with the OP's question about how to do this using React Router.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TypeScript then it is worth noting that the value of the `target` will have to be a `string` or `undefined`. Passing `null` as the value will throw a type error.

Answer (score -1):

Create a function to open the link, whether on pop up, new tab or new window. This one opens in a new tab. In your link tag, call the function. Remember to include the pathname as it is a link tag you are using.

```
let windowObjectReference;
let windowFeatures = "popup";
let instagramUrl = "https://www.instagram.com/?hl=en";

    function openInstagram(){
        windowObjectReference = window.open(instagramUrl, windowFeatures);
```