# Get the path of a certain Route in react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Using react-router in with react i have declared some routes like this:

```
<Route name="voteview" path="voteview/:baselineId" handler={VoteView}/>
```

In a React Component, i want to call this route.
React Router gives me a link:

```
<Link to="voteview" params={{baselineId: this.props.data.baselineId}}>Voteview</Link>
```

This results in a   `<a href...>` link.

But i want to use the url path programmatically, not in an `<a href...>` link. How can i get the URL path to the "voteview" route programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `makeHref` method on React Routers context to generate the path like this:

```
this.context.router.makeHref('voteview', {baselineId: this.props.data.baselineId})
```

Answer (score 2):

As of version version 1.0 of ReactRouter, `makeHref(routeName, params, query)` is now `createHref(pathname, query)`

See the v1.0.0 [Upgrade Guide](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/7ce57a496ae8e507d726003f206e0a2890184d6d/upgrade-guides/v1.0.0.md)