# how to add target=_blank on react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, hyperlink, gatsby

I need to make all the links from a text open a new tab, and the text come from  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: content,}}. the code is in a new class that extends component in react
the block of code where i pick the text id in < section>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is my solution using [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```
var content = `<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a><a href="https://google.com">Google</a>`;

class App extends React.Component {

  render(){
    return (
      <div 
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
              __html: content.replace(/href/g, "target='_blank' href")
          }}>
      </div>
    )
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 19):

Just add `rel="noopener noreferrer"` will fix your problem.

https://caniuse.com/?search=noopener%20

```html
<a href="https://hasantezcan.dev" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Go to website</a>
```

[source](https://medium.com/sedeo/how-to-fix-target-blank-a-security-and-performance-issue-in-web-pages-2118eba1ce2f#:%7E:text=The%20easy%20solutions)

Answer (score 5):

**Security**

When you use `target="_blank"` with Links, it is [recommended](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/noopener) to always set `rel="noopener"` or `rel="noreferrer"` when linking to third party content.

- `rel="noopener"` prevents the new page from being able to access the `window.opener` property and ensures it runs in a separate process. Without this, the target page can potentially redirect your page to a malicious URL.
- `rel="noreferrer"` has the same effect, but also prevents the Referer header from being sent to the new page. ⚠️ Removing the referrer header will affect analytics.

  ```
  <a href="www.google.com" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer"> Search </a>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Link to="route" target="_blank" onClick={(event) => {event.preventDefault(); window.open(this.makeHref("Your_route"));}} />
```

I Mean

```
<Link ... target="_blank">
```

OR

```
<a target='_blank' href={'Your_url'})}>Your Text</a>
```

Comment: i cant use that, because is not just a link on a static text, i have diferent posts with diferent links

Comment: Fine, Then save your dynamic url on a state and use them in the route. for example -
<Link to="route" target="_blank" onClick={(event) => {event.preventDefault(); window.open(this.makeHref({This.state.url}));}} />

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
<Link to="route" target="_blank" onClick={(event) => {event.preventDefault(); window.open(this.makeHref("route"));}} />
```

Please refer to [React-Router open Link in new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30202755/react-router-open-link-in-new-tab)

Comment: does it work on every link? and where should i place it?

Comment: Yes, it should work on every link. Please provide the necessary code snippets so that we can help you with where to place this exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than changing them up front, you can update them on the fly with a click handler.

`<div onClick={sendLinksToNewWindow}>`

```js
function sendLinksToNewWindow(event) {
    if (!(event.target instanceof HTMLElement))
        return;
    // Use .closest to handle scenario where target isn't the anchor itself. 
    // Ex: `<a href='https://example.com'><span>click here</span></a>`
    const anchor = event.target.closest('a');
    if (anchor !== null) {
        anchor.target = '_blank';
        anchor.rel = 'noopener';
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

In React, you can add the target="_blank" attribute to an anchor () element by using the dangerouslySetInnerHTML attribute, like so:

<a href={url} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: linkText}} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" />

or by using JSX and Link from react-router-dom package

import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

{linkText}

It's important to also include the rel="noopener noreferrer" attribute to prevent a potential security vulnerability.

Alternatively, you can use the onClick event to open the link in a new tab, like so:

<a href={url} onClick={(e) => {
e.preventDefault();
window.open(url, '_blank');
}}>{linkText}

This will open the link in a new tab when clicked.