# More components are getting rendered at once in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have my app on localhost:3000, and having the code below in App.js (create-react-app) , According to me on the homepage of the App only 'Burger' component should render and 'Order' component should open in a different page on click of a button that i placed somewhere in the
'Burger' Component, but what's happening is that contents of the 'Order' component are getting rendered on the homepage as well, I want only 'Burger' Component contents to be on the homepage.

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Burger from "./components/Burger/Burger";
import {
  Redirect,
  Switch,
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";
import Order from "./components/Order/Order";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Burger} exact />
        <Route path="/order" component={Order} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you provide some code from the `Burger` file?

Comment: @JeffBerlin here : https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/sM3XP4RJd6/

Comment: on line 243 you have Order component inside the Burger. That's why it's being rendered

Comment: Put Burger component below order component
        <Route path="/order" component={Order} />
        <Route path="/" component={Burger} exact />

Comment: @szczocik it's inside a fragment, i think it won't work if i put it outside the fragment.

Comment: @Fahad done that, but it's not working

Comment: @LetsCode, it is being rendered when you render a Burger component because you have the Order component inside the Burger component. If you remove it completely from Burger, it won't be rendered. 
I'm not sure why you need to have the Order component inside the Burger but if you include it there, it will be rendered

Comment: @szczocik i placed the Order inside Burger because i am passing values from Burger to Order via props , you can see Order.js here : https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ZxzK8YcD9H/

Comment: If you don't want them rendered together, then you will have to separate them, or use some conditional render. If you are passing props from Burger to Order, then perhaps you should look at global state management like Redux, so you don't have to render them both at the same time

Comment: @szczocik , i am not sure how to separate them ( I am new to ReactJS) , i was simply trying to pass from Burger to Order.

Comment: You can have a read about Redux here https://redux.js.org/faq/organizing-state
So you would have the Burger component dispatching actions to the state and the Order component, if you navigate to that route, could read from the state.

Comment: Maybe here you can find an answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30202755/react-router-open-link-in-new-tab

Comment: Where excactly do you wrap the `Router` component?

Comment: @adirabargil in the index.js

Comment: Then code sand box because i cant see any problem..