# why is my site not redirecting to social sites but mydomain/facebook?

Tags: reactjs

I seem to be having an issue where my site doesn't appear to be redirecting correctly to social sites example below

https://www.shillerslist.com/https://t.me/shillerslist

Here's my code:

```
        <Link
          class='social-icon-link telegram'
          to='/https://t.me/shillerslist'
          target='https://t.me/shillerslist'
          aria-label='Telegram'
        >
          <i class="fab fa-telegram-plane"></i>
        </Link>
```

It keeps putting my website in front of the url and I'm not sure how I can stop it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-Router open Link in new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30202755/react-router-open-link-in-new-tab)

Comment: Could it be the leading slash in the *to* attribute? I would try with `to="https://t.me/shillerslist" target="_blaknk"` instead

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<Link
  className='social-icon-link telegram'
  to='https://t.me/shillerslist'
  target="_blank"
  aria-label='Telegram'
  rel="noopener noreferrer"
>
   <i className="fab fa-telegram-plane"></i>
</Link>
```

You can also use this one as well:

```
<a href={"https://t.me/shillerslist"} target="_blank"> 
  <i className="fab fa-telegram-plane"></i>
</a>
```

Also it seems your url: `https://t.me/shillerslist` is not working

Comment: yeah this isn't it, its like I've got a redirect to my site somewhere but can't see where

Comment: There was also a '/' at the start of the url. I've updated my answer. Try the updated one

Comment: same thing occurs

Comment: So yeah that does redirect correctly but not quite what im looking for

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it, it required // at the start of the link to.

```
        <Link
          class='social-icon-link telegram'
          link to="//t.me/shillerslist"
          target='_blank'
          aria-label='Telegram'
        >
          <i class="fab fa-telegram-plane"></i>
        </Link>
```