# target _blank url not working in react js production build

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

When I clicked on the link, I got a 404 error in the production build of react js and showed an error on the firebase hosting website.

```
<Link target='_blank' to={'/property-details?id='some_id'}/>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-Router open Link in new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30202755/react-router-open-link-in-new-tab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix it, you can change your code to below.

```html
<Link to="/home" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" />
```

Just add the `rel` attribute to fix it. This may also improve your page performance.

---

If you want to use the `<a>` tag instead, then you can use the following code.

```html
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">Stack Overflow</a>
```

The `rel` attribute will improve page performance.

Answer (score 0):

That should be because you have an odd number of single quotes. Check your opening and closing quotes. From here, I can even see that the 'some_id' black color which is different from the rest of the letters when the are in quotes. They should be of the same color. I think that how I quickly figured out that the issue is probably from the single quotes.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34921972)