# Link won't open in new tab

Tags: html

I have this link in one of my webpages:

```html
<a href="https://www.myurl.com" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener" alt="no img">Link</a>
```

Initially I didn't have the `rel` but clicking it caused a 404 error on the same tab. I expected the likn to open in a new tab. I then came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71582180/7836976) but the issue didn't resolve. What could the issue be?

Comment: works for me on Chrome, just not on the snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works. I was missing a " at the end of my `href`.

```
<a href="https://www.myurl.com" target="_blank" alt="no img">Link</a>
```