# How to open Inertia link in new tab?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routes, vuejs3, inertiajs

Is there a way to open an `inertia link` in a new tab like it's possible in `anchor` tags:

```
<a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"></a>
```

This doesn't work:

```
<Link :href="..." target="_blank">
```

Comment: I think using a regular anchor tag `<a target="_blank">` should work just fine. Is there any reason you need to use the `<Link>` component?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible - so a standard anchor tag is the way to go.

This is because Inertia doesn't really need to be involved if a link will be opening in a new tab, since it doesn't have to intercept the click and perform its own server request.

Confirmed by Inertia's developer in this github issue: https://github.com/inertiajs/inertia/issues/1096

Answer (score 0):

Seems to have the same problem here
But it was a long time ago
I'm not sure which dependency version you're using now
is compatible with the issue
But you can see if that helps you
[React-Router open Link in new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30202755/react-router-open-link-in-new-tab)