# Redirect to external or internal link

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

I have a page in my application where backend decides where user should be redirected next. And it can be external link like `'google.com'` or internal `'/'`. I use `useNavigate` hook from `react-router-dom`.

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

useEffect(async () => {
  await axios.get().then((response) => {
    navigate(axios.redirectLink);
  });
});
```

It perfectly works for internal links, but doesn't work for `navigate('https://google.com')`. Then it tries to open `https://my-website/https://google.com`. What might be a solution here?

Answer (score 1):

There is no solution in navigating if you want a use Link tag do that else you can check this link as well

[React-Router open Link in new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30202755/react-router-open-link-in-new-tab)

```js
<Link to="your url" target="_blank">Test</Link>
```