# How to apply target='_blank' to a <Link> which contains an element other than just an <a>

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js, hyperlink

I am trying to open a new browser tab and redirect to the respected URL when the button is clicked, however when an element other than an anchor tag is used inside Next's `<Link>` element, it just ignores the `target="_blank"` attribute.

The structure is as below:

```
<Link passHref href={applicationUrl}>
  <Button className={styles.button}>
    <a target="_blank">Apply</a>
  </Button>
</Link>
```

I can't easily get rid of the  component in the middle, because of styling purposes. But it seems that in this structure, I can't get the applicationUrl to open in a new tab. It still redirects, but in the same browser tab.
If I remove the  component in the middle, it works though.

```
<Link passHref href={applicationUrl}>
  <a target="_blank">Apply</a>
</Link>
```

How do I get it to work without losing the styling, or duplicating CSS that is necessary?

Update:
Apparently changing the order of the `<Button>` and `<a>` is a solution.

```
<Link passHref href={applicationUrl}>
   <a target="_blank">
      <Button className={styles.button}>
         Apply
      </Button>
   </a>
</Link>
```

Comment: It's pointless to use `Link` if you're opening a new tab. Just use `a`.

Comment: The target attribute is conditional in my case, so I had to use <Link> because I might need to redirect in the same tab.

Comment: I would highly recommend you check out the following [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30202755/react-router-open-link-in-new-tab)

Comment: _"target attribute is conditional in my case"_ - Then conditionally render an `<a>` or a `<Link>` based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Set target="_blank" as a prop for the Link and it should work just fine.

```
<Link passHref href={applicationUrl} target="_blank">
   <Button className={styles.button}>
      <a>Apply</a>
   </Button>
</Link>
```

That being said, there's no reason to use a **Link** if you're opening the page in a new tab. You can just get rid of the **Link** and put the href and target in the **a** tag.

Comment: When I try to give target attribute to <Link> element, I get the following error: Property 'target' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & LinkProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'